# Property of a Javascript Class calculated from other properties in same Class

Tags: javascript, class, properties

This is probably something pretty silly that I'm missing but how do I get the property of a class to automatically re-calculate based on the values of other properties in the same class?

e.g.

```
function Test() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;
    this.prop3 = this.prop1 + this.prop2;

}

tester = new Test();

alert (tester.prop1); // expect 1
alert (tester.prop2); // expect 2
alert (tester.prop3); // expect 3

tester.prop1 += 1;

alert (tester.prop1); // expect 2
alert (tester.prop2); // expect 2
alert (tester.prop3); // expect 4
```

or do I need to have prop3 set to be = calcProp3() and then include a function like so:

```
this.calcProp3 = function() {
        var calc = this.prop1 + this.prop2;
        return calc;
    }
```

Thanks all.

Comment: You can also have a function to increase the numbers that also recalculate the rest. So instead of `tester.prop1 += 1;` you can call a function that adds a number to one and updates the rest.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> or do I need to have prop3 set to be = calcProp3() and then include a function

You have two choices:

1. Create a property with a *getter*, which looks like a simple property access when you use it, but is in fact calling a function, or
2. Do your `calcProp3` function, which makes it apparent to the coder using `Test` that they're calling a function

Option 2 is your only option if you need to support truly obsolete browsers like IE8, since IE8 doesn't support getters.

### Using a getter

Here in 2017 you'd probably define it in a `class` (transpiling if necessary for browsers that don't support ES2015's [aka "ES6"] `class`):

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;
  }
  get prop3() {
    return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
  }
}
const t = new Test();
console.log(t.prop3); // 3
t.prop1 = 2;
console.log(t.prop3); // 4
```

If you wanted to limit yourself to features of ES5 (spec released December 2009, not supported in IE8), you'd define a getter on `Test.prototype`, either by using `Object.defineProperty` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.defineproperty), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)):

```js
function Test() {
  this.prop1 = 1;
  this.prop2 = 2;
}
Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, "prop3", {
  get: function() {
    return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
  }
});
var t = new Test();
console.log(t.prop3); // 3
t.prop1 = 2;
console.log(t.prop3); // 4
```

...or by replacing `Test.prototype` and using the object initializer syntax for getters (remember to set `constructor`):

```js
function Test() {
  this.prop1 = 1;
  this.prop2 = 2;
}
Test.prototype = {
  constructor: Test,
  get prop3() {
    return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
  }
};
var t = new Test();
console.log(t.prop3); // 3
t.prop1 = 2;
console.log(t.prop3); // 4
```

### Using a function

Here in 2017, you'd probably define it as a method using `class` syntax (transpiling if necessary for older browsers):

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;
  }
  calcProp3() {
    return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
  }
}
const t = new Test();
console.log(t.calcProp3()); // 3
t.prop1 = 2;
console.log(t.calcProp3()); // 4
```

If you wanted to stick with ES5 (actually in this case ES3) features to support obsolete browsers, just add a function to the prototype:

```js
function Test() {
  this.prop1 = 1;
  this.prop2 = 2;
}
Test.prototype.calcProp3 = function calcProp3() {
  return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
};
var t = new Test();
console.log(t.calcProp3()); // 3
t.prop1 = 2;
console.log(t.calcProp3()); // 4
```

Comment: Great stuff. thank you. I didn't understand Prototype but after just watching a tutorial on it this answer now makes perfect sense. Just to check though, instead of 'Test.prototype.calcProp3 = function()' would 'Test.prototype.prop3 = function()' be just as valid? That way I could call 'Test.prop3' in exactly the same way as I would 'Test.prop1' or 'Test.prop2'? It's just a name I'm giving the function right?

Comment: @DuckinCustard: It's just a name you're giving the property that refers to a function, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript now supports a standard way to implement setters and getters via [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).

```
function Test() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;
}
Object.defineProperties(Test.prototype, {
    prop3: {
        get: function test_prop3_get(){ return this.prop1 + this.prop2 },
    },
});

tester = new Test();

alert (tester.prop1); //=> 1
alert (tester.prop2); //=> 2
alert (tester.prop3); //=> 3

tester.prop1 += 1;

alert (tester.prop1); //=> 2
alert (tester.prop2); //=> 2
alert (tester.prop3); //=> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

After ES6 you can calculate in constructor:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;
    this.suma = this.prop1 + this.prop2;
  }
  get prop3() {
    return this.suma;
  }
}
const t = new Test();
console.log(t.suma);
console.log(t.prop3); // 3
```