# Calculated property of ES6 JavaScript object can't be accessed by object method

Tags: javascript, json, oop, ecmascript-6, locale

### THE ISSUE

This is probably something simple, and I'm not really sure if this (just because it deals with objects) is an "Object-Oriented" issue. I built a JavaScript object as a learning exercise. I can access various methods and properties, however, ***methods that rely on calculated properties return undefined AND give errors. I'm not a JavaScript expert, and I started learning with jQuery about 6 years ago. Now, I'm trying to teach myself vanilla JavaScript fundamentals. Since ES6/2015 seems to be the newest method that is what I am trying to learn.

I do have some OOP experience in PHP, so I recognized some OOP concepts, but let's just say I'm a little rusty.

The trouble happens when I try to view the contents of `objActorInfo.birth.birthdateusa`:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: birthdatenumsusa is not defined
>      at Object.get birthdateusa [as birthdateusa] (:23:27)
>      at :1:20

When I console.log the whole objActorInfo object and inspect the birthdateusa property I get the following additional info:

> [Exception: ReferenceError: birthdatenumsusa is not defined at Object.get 
>   birthdateusa [as birthdateusa] (:23:27) at Object.remoteFunction
>   (:2:14)]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

### MY CODE

```js
console.clear();

var objActorInfo = {};

// function birthStrings(date) {

objActorInfo.birth = {

 /* DATES */
 birthYear4: 1960,
 birthMonthNum: 10,
 birthDayOfMO: 18,
 
 get birthDateUSA() {
  /* This method sets the values of multiple properties
   and therefore, according to my understanding, doesn't need
   to return anything.
  */
  var birthdate4USA = [this.birthMonthNum,this.birthDayOfMO,this.birthYear4].join('/');

  this.birthMonthStr = birthdate4USA.toLocaleString("en", { month: "long"  });
 },

  };

console.log(objActorInfo);
console.log("objActorInfo.birth.birthdateusa: " + objActorInfo.birth.birthdateusa);
```

### WHAT I'VE TRIED THAT HASN'T WORKED

I reviewed many links online, but most of them led to bug reports about JavaScript libraries, not with vanilla JS. I don't know much about prototyping and thus far, have not needed to. However, I have noted that the term `prototype` keeps coming up in many of the sources I'm searching. I just don't want to go down the wrong rabbit hole if I can avoid it.

These two were the posts I found the most promising:

- [Property of a Javascript Class calculated from other properties in same Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282650/property-of-a-javascript-class-calculated-from-other-properties-in-same-class)
- [Is it possible to use the computed properties to compute another properties in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173998/is-it-possible-to-use-the-computed-properties-to-compute-another-properties-in-v)

### MY QUESTIONS

1. How can I calculate birthdate (in a United States date format, *WITHOUT using any external dependencies or libraries*), store that value as a property, and then use that property over and over to calculate other properties of the same object. NOTE: **I'm not trying to constructors and instances and such. This is just a basic JavaScript object.**
2. How can I use an on-the-fly calculated property or method as a stored value to calculate other property values of the same object?
3. How can I get a month name string from a date object using modern ES6 JavaScript techniques including the `toLocaleString()` function.

Comment: Your code references `birthdatenumsusa` without `this.`; it's not a local variable, it's a property of the object. I would suggest using variable names that are less confusingly similar.

Comment: Also, you're trying to use `.toLocaleString()` on a plain array; I don't know what you expect that to do, but that array is *not* a Date instance.

Comment: Also also, your `birthdateusa` getter doesn't bother to return anything. Using a getter as a method to mutate an object is pretty unconventional. What would be more "normal" would be to have the getter check to see if the internal computed value already exists, and initialize it if not; and in either case it would return the value.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. So, by checking and initializing, do you mean something like?:

`get birthdateusa() {
 return this.birthdate_nums_usa = this.birthdate_nums_usa ? this.birthdate_nums_usa : [this.birthmonthnum,this.birthdayofmo,this.birthyear].join('/');
}`

Comment: You still aren't making an actual Date instance from the date parts. You need to do that in order to make `.toLocaleString()` work. Just gluing the date parts together with "/" won't give you a Date.

Comment: @Pointy Darn! You are right. So, I need to create a date object and feed it the date string first. Such a rookie mistake. I'll work on it tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `birthdatenumsusa`

```
    var birthdatenumsusa = [this.birthmonthnum,this.birthdayofmo,this.birthyear].join('/');
    this.birthdatenumsusa = birthdatenumsusa;
```

When writing JavaScript, camelCase is convention and would make small errors like that more noticeable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ok, I made updates locally ... should I change the code in the question to reflect it?

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 Are you still running into other issues with your code? If so, then yes, add it to your question and update the context. If everything is resolved... then I think a simple check mark will suffice.

Comment: No, it is not resolved. I have made adjustments to simplify the code and have changed the code according to the advice given so far by @Pointy and yourself. Thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 Ah, my mistake. You seem like you have a good understanding of OO principles, so I think the docs for the `Date` object should answer all of your questions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date . After that, `parseFloat` converts a string into a float, or `parseInt` for string -> int

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to look into it tomorrow and report back.