# Javascript object value variable

Tags: javascript, object, calculation

I want to do some calculation inside an js-object. Is this possible?

```
foo: [
{
 value: 1000
 target:50
 process: (target*value)/100
},
{
 value: 500
 target:100
 process: (target*value)/100
}]
```

The `process` key should be calculated from `value` and `target`. Is there a way to to this?js

Comment: You could make it into a class with a getter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282650/property-of-a-javascript-class-calculated-from-other-properties-in-same-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `process` a getter:

```js
const foo = [
  {
    value: 1000,
    target: 50,
    get process() {
      return (this.target * this.value) / 100;
    }
  },
  {
    value: 500,
    target: 100,
    get process() {
      return (this.target * this.value) / 100;
    }
  }
];
```

And then use property access:

```js
console.log(foo[0].process); //=> 500
console.log(foo[1].process); //=> 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Process should be a function or an accessor:

```js
var foo= [
    {
     value: 1000,
     target:50,
     process() { return (this.target*this.value)/100}
    },
    {
     value: 500,
     target:100,
     process() { return (this.target*this.value)/100}
    }]
    // use it like this:
    console.log(foo[0].process()); //=> 500
    console.log(foo[1].process()); //=> 500
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.
Why not just

```
  const process = (target*value)/100;
   foo: [
    {
     value: 1000
     target:50
     process: process
    },
    {
     value: 500
     target:100
     process: process 
    }]
```

Or, if you want, a Class can be useful for that case:

```
class Foo
{
 constructor: (value, target) { 
    this.value = value;
    this.target = target;
    this.process = (target*value)/100;
 }
}
```

and then just:

```
foo: [
     new Foo(500, 100),
new Foo(1000, 50)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could start by storing the "raw values" (`value` and `target` properties) in an array:

```
const rawData = [{ value: 1000, target: 50 }, { value: 500, target: 100 }];
```

and then `map` over that to add the computed property:

```
const foo = rawData.map(({ value, target }) => ({ value, target, process: target * value / 100 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the object is in javascript, add some calculations after the object. Like so:

```
let foo = [{
 value: 1000,
 target:50,
 process:0
},
{
 value: 500,
 target:100,
 process:0
}];
foo[0]["process"] = foo[0]["target"] * foo[0]["value"];
foo[1]["process"] = foo[1]["target"] * foo[1]["value"];
console.log(foo[0]["process"]); // ==> 50000
console.log(foo[1]["process"]); // ==> 50000
```